# AWS EC2インスタンスタイプc系利用形態について

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2

現在 t3.medium で運用してるシステムがあるのですが
ユーザ数や機能が増えるにつれて常時クレジットが枯渇しはじめているので
グレードアップを検討中です

現在のボトルネックはCPUで
https://aws.amazon.com/jp/ec2/pricing/on-demand/
ここを見るとt3 の次のグレード t3.large はメモリが 4 => 8 に倍増するかわりに
CPUは変わらないように見えます
ちなみに ECPU の変数というのがどういう意味なのでしょうか

あと
https://dev.classmethod.jp/cloud/aws/comparison-wordpress-c5/
こちらのサイトで c5.large と t3.medium の比較をされていて
料金が約２倍でCPU使用率が半減（リソースが倍？）になってるみたいなので
c5.large への乗り換えを検討しているのですが
t2 t3 系しか使ったことがなく c 系ではクレジットや料金体系がどう変わるのか教えていただきたいです

t 系は基本料金では CPU平均 20% しか使えないかわりにクレジットによるバーストができるのですが
c 系の料金では何％まで使用できてバースト相当の機能や追加料金に関してはどうなってるんでしょうか

調べてもドキュメントがみあたらなかったので誘導していただけるだけでも助かります

また C5.large 以外にもおすすめのタイプがあれば教えていただければ幸いです

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECUはAmazonが規定するCPU能力値です（[FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/ec2/faqs/#Hardware_information)の下の方）。「変数」とは英語ページの「Variable」の訳語ですが、より適切には「可変」の方が伝わりやすいでしょうか。バーストにより変化することを表現したいのだと思います。

---

[バーストパフォーマンスインスタンス](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/ec2/instance-types/#Burstable_Performance_Instances)

> Amazon EC2 では、定常パフォーマンスのインスタンス (例: M5、C5、R5) とバーストパフォーマンスインスタンス (例: T3) を選択できます。

と説明されています。T3/T2でなければ定常パフォーマンスであり、100%利用可能です。